# Email to SFDC Logged Task Records Do Not Trigger Workflows?

Tags: email, api, workflow

My problem is I am trying to get a workflow to trigger when an email is logged in SFDC from a bcc

I set the workflow trigger to be:

**Subject** *Starts with* **Email:**

This only works if I go back and edit the task after the task has been logged it does not trigger on creation

Do Email to SFDC Logged Task Records Not Trigger Workflows?

Comment: Your workflow is set everytime a record is created and updated?